# using values from asyncronius function in syncronius function

Tags: javascript

First, please excuse my bad English. I'm not use to write in English.

I'm using Node.js and i have variables that sometimes get their value from async functions and sometimes by direct assignment (ex:

```
async(function(data) {
    var x= data.something
}; or x = 5;)
```

the problem is that later on the have shared code which forces me to duplicate the code.
in syncronius scripting i usually do an if.. else statement to seperate the cases and assign. ex:

```
if(boolivar){
    var x = niceFunc();
}
else {
    var x = 5;
}
coolFunc(x);
```

now days im forced to to this:

```
if(boolivar){
    niceFUnc(function(X){
        coolFunc(X);
    }
}
else{
    var x = 5;
    coolFunc(X);
}
```

does someone has an idea how to solve my problem?
I thought about forcing the async function to be sync but:
a. i dont know how
b. it kind of ruins the whole point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it essentially as you have, except that I would abstract the sync/async calls so that it doesn't make any difference to the code that's using it what's really happening behind the scenes (ignore the bad function names; I have no idea what your code does):

```
function doNiceFunc(boolivar, callback) {
    if (boolivar) {
        niceFUnc(function(x) {
            callback(x);
        });
    } else {
        callback(5);
    }
}
```

Now `doNiceFunc` appears the same in both cases from the outside:

```
doNiceFunc(boolivar, function(x) {
    coolFunc(x);
});
```

I've used this exact pattern in a library that retrieved data that was sometimes immediately available and other times had to be retrieved from the network. The users of this library didn't have to care which was the case at any given time, because the call looked the same in both situations.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this lib [node-sync](https://github.com/0ctave/node-sync)

```
var sync = require('sync');
sync(function(){
  var result = query.sync(query, params);
  // result can be used immediately
})
```